# Is it possible to create model of a table from a given table of database in django model

Tags: django

I want to create Only model of single database, Through InspectDB we can create model of complete database. But I am not very clear how to create one table model in Django?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can tell `inspectdb` to generate code only for a certain table. You can just use `inspectdb` for all tables, and then only use the code generated for the table you want. The modelname usually is the `CamelCased` version of your `underscored_table_name`.

Comment: "You can just use inspectdb for all tables, and then only use the code generated for the table you want. " I did this but actually there are around 400 tables, I didnt want to do this. anyway thanks